# Strange behavior when returning ObjectNode from IntegrationFlows

Tags: spring-integration

When an ObjectNode is passed from the extractFramesFlow() and reaches the httpCallbackFlow(), HTTP request is successfully performed and JSON formatted payload is 'POST'ed to the "call_back" **uri** specified.

```
 @Bean
public IntegrationFlow extractFramesFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(extractFramesChannel())
            .handle(ObjectNode.class, (payload, headers) -> {
        payload = validateFields(payload);
        String path = payload.get("path").asText();
        try {
            File moviePath = new File(path);
            ArrayNode arrayNode = mapper.createArrayNode();
            String imageType = payload.path("image_type").asText("JPG");
            String prefix = payload.path("prefix").asText();
            Tools.thumbnails(moviePath, payload.get("slice").asInt(), payload.get("scale").asInt(),
                    imageType, prefix, file -> arrayNode.add(file.toString()));
            payload.set("files", arrayNode);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return payload;
    }).enrichHeaders(h-> h.header("errorChannel", "asyncErrorChannel", true))
            .<ObjectNode, Boolean>route(p-> !p.hasNonNull("id"),
            m->m.channelMapping("true","httpCallbackFlow.input")
                    .channelMapping("false","uploadToS3Channel")).get();
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow httpCallbackFlow() {
    return f->f.handle(Http.<JsonNode>outboundChannelAdapter(m->m.getPayload().get("call_back").asText()));
}
```

However, when an ObjectNode is chained from the handleAsyncErrors() flow and reaches the same httpCallbackFlow(), we get an Exception which is caused by

org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Could not write request: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for request type [com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode] and content type [application/x-java-serialized-object]
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$HttpEntityRequestCallback.doWithRequest(RestTemplate.java:811)
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:594)
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:572)
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:493)
        at org.springframework.integration.http.outbound.HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler.handleRequestMessage(HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler.java:382)
        ... 24 more

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow handleAsyncErrors() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(asyncErrorChannel())
            .<MessagingException>handle((p, h) -> {
                ObjectNode objectNode = mapper.createObjectNode();
                objectNode.put("call_back", "http://some.test.uri");
                return objectNode;
            }).channel("httpCallbackFlow.input").get();
}
```

I don't know why we get this Exception handled by the same exact IntegrationFlow notwithstanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message on the error flow has no `contentType` header.

It is an error message with the `MessagingException` payload; which has 2 properties; the `cause` and `failedMessage`.

Presumably you have a content type on the main flow message. You can set the content type with a header enricher, or add

```
.<MessagingException, Message<?>>transform(p -> p.getFailedMessage())
```

before your existing error handler, to restore the headers from the failed message.

Comment: Thank you for your response, You are right. the IntegrationFlow accepts POST request from a http client and its contentType header value is set to "application/json" as you've pointed out. The message is processed  asynchronously and the result will be sent back to the "call_back" URL defined in the request payload which is a JSON. It may not be a good practice to reuse the header in this fashion.

Comment: Yes; it would be better to explicitly set the `contentType` with a header enricher (overwrite=true) rather than relying on it being set by some upstream component (such as inheriting it from an inbound request).